# Get Ada locked with asset from db-sync query?

Tags: native-assets, ada, cardano-db-sync

Does anybody know a way to get the locked asset Ada/tAda information from db-sync? identical to the information displayed in Nami wallet?

[image]

I've tried looking at all the tables, but nothing seems to hold this value.
could this value be calculated some other way by combining or summing? any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: All native asset transactions are associated with an ADA transaction. The ADA transaction has a transaction id, and it is probably a way to track locked asset by looking at the ADA transaction id.

Comment: @ErikdeCastroLopo Thanks for your suggestion, although I'm sadly still stuck on this issue. I created a new question here https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/8703/can-anyone-explain-how-tada-locked-with-asset-is-calculated because a more confusing problem came up surrounding locked tAda with assets. thanks again!