# Can anyone explain how tAda locked with asset is calculated?

Tags: native-assets, cardano-db-sync, nami-wallet, eternl

I have previously asked a similar question here [Get Ada locked with asset from db-sync query?](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/8661/get-ada-locked-with-asset-from-db-sync-query) but I'm still really stuck with this and needing some help.

After looking at Nami Wallet, Eternl Wallet and DB-Sync I am now totally confused because it would appear that each show a different value for tAda locked with assets.

[image]

**Nami shows tAda locked with assets as 0.193950t₳,

Eternl shows tAda locked with assets as 3.676430t₳

DB-Sync shows tAda with assets as 4.241040t₳**

Can anyone help explain what is going on here? and more importantly how to get the correct value for the total tAda that is locked with all assets? to be honest I didn't think it would be this challenging or confusing.

Any help on this is appreciated!

Also thanks to Erik de Castro Lopo for giving me your suggestion on my last question but sadly I'm still at a loss.

Comment: I am only familiar with `db-sync`. What is the query you are running there?

Answer (score 0):

In Cardano, each UTxO can contain a heterogeneous mixture of tokens and data, but must contain at least some amount of ADA (in this case, tADA as you are in Testnet). This is done on purpose to prevent both inadvertent and malicious chain bloat. You can read more about `minUTXOvalues` [here](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-ledger/blob/master/doc/explanations/min-utxo-alonzo.rst).

On your Eternl wallet, you probably have a couple UTxOs with tokens such that the min amount of ADA in each of those UTxO's totals to the locked amount displayed to you by Eternl.

I know that Eternl calculation is accurate, I am not sure about Nami.

Finally, keep in mind that `db-sync` is not showing "tADA **locked** with assets" but "tADA with assets": these amounts are different.